# Include alembic as part of a custom installer script, to create or upgrade database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am sending users a python script which will install our product.  As part of the installation, I want to be able to create a set of database tables as well.

It seems that alembic would be perfect for the job; because for each upgrade of our product, I could have alembic upgrade the database.

In order to make this REALLY simple for our users, is  there a way to:

- Include alembic as part of our distribution, without forcing the end user to run pip to install it?
- Call alembic from a python script, so we can do everything in Python (without having to create a bat or sh file)?

This has to run cross-platform, so any platform-dependent steps of the installation (e.g, like running "make") are less than desireable.